# Chartjs Radar - Change color of end point labels

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js

I need to change the color of the labels displayed at each point on the chart, I have tried many different things without any result at all.

**Image**

[image]

**Code**

```
                    const CHART = document.getElementById("radar_chart");
                    Chart.defaults.scale.ticks.beginAtZero = true;
                    Chart.defaults.scale.ticks.max = 10;
                    Chart.defaults.scale.ticks.display = false;
                    Chart.defaults.scale.ticks.display = false;

                    var radar = new Chart(CHART, {
                        type: 'radar',
                        data: {
                            labels: ["Team", "Potential", "Risk", "Social", "Hype"],
                            datasets: [
                                {
                                    backgroundColor: "#2e4259cc",
                                    borderColor: "#fff",
                                    borderWidth: 3,
                                    pointBorderColor: "#fff",
                                    pointBackgroundColor: "#2e4259",
                                    pointHoverRadius: 5,
                                    data: [3, 5, 9, 5, 8]
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        options: {
                            legend: {
                                display: false,
                                fontColor: "#fff",
                                labels: {
                                    fontColor: '#fff'
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    });
```

My latest effort was changing pointLabelFontColor but with no luck, i can't seem to find anything about it

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
options:{
  scale:{
    pointLabels:{
       fontColor:"red",
    },
}
```

In theory this should be the configuration you should use if we follow the doc for the [Linear Radial Axis](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/2.7.3/axes/radial/linear.html#linear-radial-axis)

The doc is for the version 2.7.2, so I am not sure it would work for your version, or if it would be any different in older version.

Comment: I use 2.7.0 it does not work in this version, i will try getting the newest version and get back to you

Comment: @iiiml0sto1 What happen if you try to put my config in scale ? To be honest I have been struggling with their documentation too

Comment: Thats it! idk why i cant set this directly like this Chart.defaults.scale.pointLabels.fontColor = "red" but it worked the other way around, thanks alot! :)

Comment: I am not sure neither to be honest! No problem!

Answer (score 1):

```
options: {
        scales: {
            r: {
          
                pointLabels:{
                    color: 'rgb(54, 162, 235)',
                },

            },
}
```

I don’t know what version you are using, but the current configuration works for me.

[image: configuration works for me]

Comment: Nice! It's working for me. I am using version 3.7.0.